# webpack-hot-middleware always reloads the page hot reloading not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr, webpack-hot-middleware

I looked  on all manuals but still my app after code change refreshes all the page not hot reloads the specific change any idea why? webpack.config:

```
export default {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    './src/index',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000&reload=true', //note that it reloads the page if hot module reloading fails.
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist', // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  externals: {
    "$": "jQuery"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /\.css/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader'},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
      {test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url?limit=250000'}
    ]
  },
  postcss: function () {
    return [precss, autoprefixer];
  }
};
```

index.js

```
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  hot:true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));


app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
  log: console.log,
  path: '/__webpack_hmr',
  heartbeat: 10 * 1000,
}));


app.use('/static',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../src')));


app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, '../src/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: did you eventually work this out? I may be having a similar problem.